# Is it possible to convert a washing machine motor to become a useful wind-turbine generator?

Tags: generator, windturbine

I'm looking for a way to acquire a generator for a wind-turbine. The generator should produce a lot of energy with very low RPM. Also I don't want expensive options. One thing I'm thinking about is to use an old washing machine motor. I saw some videos on youtube that a washing-machine motor can be used as DC generator, but not sure how good it will be in terms of generating energy at low RPMs. And I couldn't find a satisfying answer elsewhere.

I'm looking for something that can give at least 100 Volt, at 2500 rpm.

So is it possible to convert a washing machine motor to become a **useful** wind-turbine generator at such values?

Comment: How old or new is the washing machine? Old ones tends to be brushed universal motors which can’t be used as generators. Newer ones have three phase inverters for speed control, but if the motor is asynchronous, you are pretty much out of luck again. What you need is a permanent magnet motor.

Comment: There are many youtube videos and other websites covering making wind turbines.

Comment: There is a well known New Zealand brand of washing machine that lends itself to such hacking. I bet the YT videos used that brand. Maybe look out for one of those...

Comment: (Non-new ones may even be pole-switching ASM. A photograph (of the motor) may go a long way.)